# Union and intersection of an indexed family

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

1) Compare:
$\bigcup_{j \in J} \bigcap_{i \in I} X_{i,j}$ and $\bigcap_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in J} X_{i,j}$

2) Prove that:
$$\bigcap_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in J} X_{i,j} = \bigcup_{f \in F(I,J)} \bigcap_{i \in I} X_{i,f(i)}$$
where F(I,J) is the set of all the function from I to J.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any hint would be appreciable

Comment: $$\bigcup_{j \in J} \bigcap_{i \in I} X_{i,j} = \{x\mid \exists j \,\forall i, x \in  X_{i,j} \}$$ Now figure out what the other expression is in set-builder notation. Can you figure out how the two sets relate now?

Comment: $\bigcap_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in J} X_{i,j} = \{x\mid \forall i \,\exists j, x \in  X_{i,j} \}$, so the first set is in the second set, am I right? Also, does anyone have a hint for the second exercice?

Comment: Yes, the LHS requires one $j$ that works for all of the $i$, while the RHS only requires that each $i$ has some $j$ that works. Obviously if there is a $j$ that works for all $i$, then each $i$ has a $j$ that works. But vice versa need not be true. For (2) my first hint is to do the same thing: Express both sets in Set-Builder notation. Then choose $x$ in the LHS and ask does the fact that for each $i$ there is a $j$ with $x \in X_{i,j}$ imply that there is a function $f: I \to J$ with $x \in X_{i,f(j)}$ for all $i$? And vice versa?